# Websocket automatically closes after response in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

The following code is run as a server and browser clients connect.
However after each request the browser is showing that websocket connection is closed. I want to keep connection open in browser clients as reopening is making it slow due to network issues etc.
Earlier with Nodejs websocket servers it never closed the connections.

Can anybody tell me where and how socket may be getting closed:

```
# WSS (WS over TLS) server example, with a self-signed certificate


from common import *
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from pathlib import Path
import re
import time
import os.path
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("Started time=", dt_string)

def decode_batch_predictions(pred):
    input_len = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]
    # Use greedy search. For complex tasks, you can use beam search
    results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][
              :, :8
              ]
    # Iterate over the results and get back the text
    output_text = []
    for res in results:
        condition = tf.less(res, 0)
        res = tf.where(condition, 1, res)
        res = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(res)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        output_text.append(res)
    return output_text


characters = [' ', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
              'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
              'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

characters = np.asarray(characters, dtype='<U1')
num_to_char = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=characters, mask_token=None, invert=True
)

prediction_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_prediction2')
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
prediction_model.compile(optimizer=opt)

gg_hashmap = None

frameinfo = getframeinfo(currentframe())

async def hello(websocket, path):
    global gg_hashmap

    print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    json_data = await websocket.recv()

    obj = json.loads(json_data)
    #print(obj, flush=True)


    if ("l" in obj and obj["l"]=='license'):


        res = {
            'status': 1,
            'python': 1,

        }



        json_string = json.dumps(res)

        await websocket.send(json.dumps(json_string))
    else:
        print("In else pat")


def start_server():
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)

    ssl_context.load_cert_chain("bundle.pem", "key.pem");

    ip = ''

    if os.name == 'nt':
        ip = '127.0.0.1'
    else:
        ip = "0.0.0.0"

    start_server = websockets.serve(
        hello, ip, 31334, ssl=ssl_context
    )

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_compaserver.pyplete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()


def main():
    print("Entered main")
    global gg_hashmap
    gg_hashmap = getHash();
    start_server()
    print("Server started")




main()
```

Comment: Did you try to add error handling to the hello() method? add a try except block around the websocket.recv() and send() with `websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError` and check what the output might be to at least provide better context to the issue.

Comment: I'm a beginner with Python. I guess some silly issue i'm missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote does not explicitly close the WebSocket connection. In a typical Python WebSocket server implementation using the [`websockets` library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), a WebSocket connection remains open unless explicitly closed by either the server or the client, or unless an unhandled exception occurs that causes the coroutine (in this case, the `hello` function) to exit.

In your case, I would check if there is an exception that terminates the `hello` coroutine, which would effectively close the WebSocket connection.

Adding exception handling and logging can help you identify if this is the case, included, as commented a [try except bloc](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp).

```py
async def hello(websocket, path):
    try:
        global gg_hashmap
        print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

        json_data = await websocket.recv()
        # rest of your code...
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception occurred: {e}")
```

---

Check also the [websockets library FAQ](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/server.html#why-does-the-server-close-the-connection-prematurely) like:

It includes:

> websockets takes care of closing the connection when the handler exits

In the context of the `websockets` library, the "handler" refers to the coroutine that handles the WebSocket connection—in your case, the `hello` function. If this function exits for any reason, the WebSocket library will automatically close the corresponding WebSocket connection.

In your existing code, the `hello` function does not have a loop to keep it running and listening for messages continuously. Once it receives a message and processes it, the function reaches its end, which would cause the WebSocket library to close the connection.

To keep the connection open, you could introduce a loop inside your `hello` function that continues to listen for incoming messages. For example:

```py
async def hello(websocket, path):
    try:
        global gg_hashmap

        while True:  # Loop to keep the connection open
            print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

            json_data = await websocket.recv()

            # Your existing code...
            await websocket.send(json.dumps(json_string))

    except ConnectionClosedError as e:
        print(f"Connection closed unexpectedly: {e}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
```

Adding a `while True` loop will keep the handler running, keeping the WebSocket connection open until an explicit close request is received or an exception occurs.

Comment: Beat me to it by a long shot (should've read answers before writing my own code... almost identical to what you posted). Any idea why this isn't accepted?

Comment: There is no exception as you've suggested. However the loop has solved the problem and the response is reduced from 2sec to .5 seconds due to reuse of connection. Thanks for this Loop

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your code that you are not importing the `asyncio` module for use in the lines, which may not be executed.

```py
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Please use `import asyncio`.

Another point is that you should add a ping to your WebSocket client to keep the WebSocket connection active, as it closes the connection by default. Add a ping every at least 20 seconds, as in the method below:

```py
async def send_ping(websocket):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(20)  # Wait for 20 seconds
        ping_message = {"type": "ping"}  # Create a ping message
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(ping_message))
        print("Sent ping message")
```

In this example, the `send_ping` function is responsible for sending the "ping" message every 20 seconds. Periodic sending is achieved using `await asyncio.sleep(20)`, which waits for 20 seconds before sending the message again. Make sure to adjust the "ping" message and processing logic in the WebSocket server as needed to fit your specific use case.

Comment: `as it closes the connection by default` how fast? in milliseconds or seconds?

Comment: The websocket client waits up to 2 minutes by default to close if it does not receive a response from the websocket server, but I tested and also verified that it closed well before that on a web server with apache, this type of connection changes, interfering with the response time. In this case, you must make some settings on the webapache server such as mod_proxy_wstunnel etc... What other services are you using in this application?

Answer (score -1):

WebSocket connections should ideally remain open until either the client or server decides to close them explicitly. However, in your code, I don't see any logic that explicitly closes the WebSocket connections. WebSocket connections typically close due to errors or other issues.

Here are some common reasons why WebSocket connections may be closing unexpectedly:

Error Handling: Check if there are any error conditions that might cause the server to close the WebSocket connections. Look for exceptions or error messages in your server logs.

Client Disconnects: WebSocket connections can be closed by the client. Ensure that your client-side code is not explicitly closing the connection.

Idle Timeout: Some WebSocket libraries or servers have an idle timeout setting that closes connections that have been inactive for a certain period. Check if your WebSocket server has such a setting, and if so, adjust it if needed.

Network Issues: You mentioned concerns about network issues. Ensure that there are no network problems that might lead to the connections being closed.

Server Crashes: If your server crashes or encounters an unhandled exception, it can result in WebSocket connections being closed. Make sure your server code is robust and handles exceptions gracefully.

Concurrency Issues: If your server is handling multiple connections concurrently, ensure that there are no race conditions or shared resource issues that could lead to connection closures.

To diagnose the issue further, you can add more logging and error handling to your server code. Additionally, you may want to check the WebSocket library or framework you are using for any specific configuration options related to connection management and timeouts.

I hope this code fix your problem!

**Code:**

```
from common import *
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from pathlib import Path
import re
import time
import os.path
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

def decode_batch_predictions(pred):
    input_len = np.ones(pred.shape[0]) * pred.shape[1]
    results = keras.backend.ctc_decode(pred, input_length=input_len, greedy=True)[0][0][:, :8]
    output_text = []
    for res in results:
        condition = tf.less(res, 0)
        res = tf.where(condition, 1, res)
        res = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(res)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        output_text.append(res)
    return output_text

characters = [' ', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
              'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
              'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

characters = np.asarray(characters, dtype='<U1')
num_to_char = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=characters, mask_token=None, invert=True
)

prediction_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_prediction2')
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()
prediction_model.compile(optimizer=opt)

gg_hashmap = None

frameinfo = getframeinfo(currentframe())

async def hello(websocket, path):
    global gg_hashmap
    print(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    json_data = await websocket.recv()
    obj = json.loads(json_data)
    if ("l" in obj and obj["l"] == 'license'):
        res = {
            'status': 1,
            'python': 1,
        }
        json_string = json.dumps(res)
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(json_string))
    else:
        print("In else part")

def start_server():
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain("bundle.pem", "key.pem")
    ip = ''
    if os.name == 'nt':
        ip = '127.0.0.1'
    else:
        ip = "0.0.0.0"
    start_server = websockets.serve(hello, ip, 31334, ssl=ssl_context)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

def main():
    global gg_hashmap
    gg_hashmap = getHash()
    start_server()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```